# Why is the Play button disabled in Vermintide 2?

Tags: warhammer-vermintide-2

I'm trying to play Vermintide 2 but the play button in-game is grayed out, so I can't click on it. I played one match earlier today, so I know it has been enabled in the past.

[image: Image showing the "Quick Play" screen with an inactive "PLAY" button.]

How can I play the game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to simply select a difficulty and the button will become enabled as per [this source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/552500/discussions/0/2650805184969575926/):

> You have to click and actually select a specific difficulty